# Lucene QueryParser and how to add a global filter?

Tags: lucene

I have three fields in the index; firstname, lastname, and isManager (1 or 0).
How do I go about using the QueryParser and add isManager (as a global filter) to 1 only so that I am effectively searching for the managers only?

So, if user searches for/passes in "firstname:john", I would like to add/append "isManager:1" as a global filter. One solution is to append "NOT isManager:0" to all the user's query string... but was wondering if there's any other preferred way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the Query object you get back from QueryParer using FilteredQuery http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FilteredQuery.html

Answer (score 0):

Using [query filters](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FilteredQuery.html) is the right way to do it.

The problem with appending is that theoretically this is prone to query injection attacks (think [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) but for Lucene queries).